# How to filter a "}"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have no idea how to remove "}". My code is below,

```
INPUTSCRIPT="CLOSEDLOOP{DCSOURCE1|VOLTAGE|0.1|-1|5|1000}"
TEMPSCRIPT=INPUTSCRIPT.split('|')
STR_SETTELING=TEMPSCRIPT[5]
STR_SETTELING
```

Output Query,

```
 '1000}'
```

So, I would like to remove "}" after "1000" and no idea how to do.

Many Thanks.

Comment: `STR_SETTELING.rstrip('}')` or `STR_SETTELING[:-1]` or `filter(str.isdigit, STR_SETTELING)`

Comment: I think you should map your input string with a more complex logic/tool (e.g. regular expression: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

Comment: Don, Do you mind to show me an example? I am new to Python. Sorry to trouble you..

Comment: No need for regular expressions until you want to do more fancy stuff; it'll only increase the complexity and unreadability of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what is happening behind the scenes by printing your variable in the shell,

```
>>> INPUTSCRIPT="CLOSEDLOOP{DCSOURCE1|VOLTAGE|0.1|-1|5|1000}"
>>> TEMPSCRIPT=INPUTSCRIPT.split('|')
>>> TEMPSCRIPT
['CLOSEDLOOP{DCSOURCE1', 'VOLTAGE', '0.1', '-1', '5', '1000}']
>>> TEMPSCRIPT[5]
'1000}'
```

Further refinement required,

```
>>> TEMPSCRIPT[5].rstrip('}')
'1000'
```